# Emitting a singal from QChartViews mouseMoveEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to pass the variable "event" from QChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) to my MainWindow, so I can use it in my MainWindow. Since I am new to Qt and dont know exactly how to do it, I tried to subclass QChartView and override the function mouseMoveEvent, but I can only call static functions from this method, which are in my MainWindow class, but I need to call a non static function, so I can access variables and functions in my MainWindow class.
Is it possible to solve this problem with signals? My first attempt was this:

```
connect(this, ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event), ui->chartView, SLOT(showInformation(QMouseEvent*)));
```

But it didnt work. Is there a way to emit a signal which executes a function in my MainWindow every time when ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) is called?

Comment: Event handlers like `mouseMoveEvent` are not signals. You can define your own signal and emit it from your override of `mouseMoveEvent` virtual method.

Comment: "I tried to subclass `QChartView` and override the function `mouseMoveEvent`, but I can only call static functions from this method" That's not true - you can happily call non-static functions of your derived class, or emit signals defined therein.